# How do you stop text weight from changing in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I just updated to PyCharm 2019 and now the font weight in the editor changes as I click around. Font weight also changes in the project explorer. I find this to be very distracting and would like to turn this off however I can not find a way to do so in preferences.

How do I disable this?

Comment: Provide a video/screencast or something. There is no way to see what you have got there (what setup / what theme is used etc etc).

Comment: Based on your limited description, it could be this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1348. Check comments there.